# Map function not able to implement in reactJS app

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and have created a simple app from a tutorial. In the tutorial, they have used stateless components whereas I changed to stateful components.
But I'm getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I don't know where my code is getting wrong. It seems to be all right for me.

---

*message-list.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MessageView from './message-view';

class MessageList extends Component {
  state = {
    messages: [
      {
        from: 'John',
        message: 'The event will start next week',
        status: 'unread'
      },
      {
        from: 'Martha',
        message: 'I will be traveling soon',
        status: 'read'
      },
      {
        from: 'Jacob',
        message: 'Talk later. Have a great day!',
        status: 'read'
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { messageViews } = this.state.messages;
    console.log(messageViews);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>List of Messages</h1>
        {messageViews.map(msgList => (
          <MessageView message={msgList.messages} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MessageList;
```

---

*message-view.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MessageView extends Component {
  render() {
    const list = this.props.message;
    console.log(list);

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="from">
          <span className="label">From : </span>
          <span className="value">{list.name} </span>
        </div>

        <div className="status">
          <span className="label">Status : </span>
          <span className="value">{list.status}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="message">
          <span className="label">Message : </span>
          <span className="value">{list.content} </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MessageView;
```

---

I have tried searching why map function is not working but of no-avail. I'm very much new to react. Can someone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few basic issues in your code

**First:** The state messages doesn't contain a key called as messageViews and hence you get the error

**Second:** In the message view Component, you aren't accessing the correct keys ie. `from, message` instead of `name, content`

Working code

```
class MessageList extends Component {
  state = {
    messages: [
      {
        from: "John",
        message: "The event will start next week",
        status: "unread"
      },
      {
        from: "Martha",
        message: "I will be traveling soon",
        status: "read"
      },
      {
        from: "Jacob",
        message: "Talk later. Have a great day!",
        status: "read"
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { messages: messageViews } = this.state;
    console.log(messageViews);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>List of Messages</h1>
        {messageViews.map(msgList => <MessageView message={msgList} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MessageList;

class MessageView extends Component {
  render() {
    const list = this.props.message;
    console.log({ list });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="from">
          <span className="label">From : </span>
          <span className="value">{list.from} </span>
        </div>

        <div className="status">
          <span className="label">Status : </span>
          <span className="value">{list.status}</span>
        </div>

        <div className="message">
          <span className="label">Message : </span>
          <span className="value">{list.message} </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4rr367kn5x)**

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

In order to fix this error, you should remove the curly brackets surround the `messageViews` like this

```js
 render() {
    const messageViews = this.state.messages;  //removed the curly brackets
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>List of Messages</h1>
        {messageViews.map(msgList => (
          <MessageView message={msgList.messages} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Because when you write like this:

```
const { messageViews } = this.state.messages
```

It will try to destructure the `this.state.messages` object and as we all see, their is no property `messageViews` exists. Hence, the `messageViews` is **undefined**.

And then, when you use the `map()` method like `messageViews.map(msgList => (...))` , the program will try to call the `map()` method of an **undefined** variable. That is why you got the error: *Cannot read property 'map' of undefined*